# How do I setup gradle for different product flavors and different icons depending on releas/debug?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to have different images depending on product flavor and if its debug or release, what is the proper setup of the res folder to achieve this?

In my build.gradle:

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        applicationId   "com.myapp.flavor1"
    }
    flavor2 {
        applicationId   "com.myapp.flavor2"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        useProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

In my folder strucure I now have:

```
src/flavor1/res
   /flavor2/res
   /main/res
   /debug/res
```

I've tried having in my debug folder have flavor1 and flavor2 as subfolders with resources, but that does not apply. Only having a res folder in debug results in same assets for both flavors, whereas I want them to be different. So how do I setup the project so I have different images depending on debug/release and the different product flavors?

EDIT:

updated folder structure

Comment: You can have a res folder inside each of those folders containing the specific resources

Comment: Yes, I do have it. But I don't manage to get different resources depending on debug/release. So I want to have 4 different sets of images resources; flavor1/debug, flavor1/release, flavor2/debug, flavor2/release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually easier than you might think.

You currently have:

```
src/flavor1/res
   /flavor2/res
   /main/res
   /debug/res
```

Just add:

```
src/flavor1Debug/res
   /flavor1Release/res
   /flavor2Debug/res
   /flavor2Release/res
```

Resources in there will override the ones in the less-specific folders.

The 'Build Variants' UI in Android Studio is helpful to confirm the final set of possibilities.

I use this pattern myself for Google Maps API keys, which in my case need to be different per-customer (flavour) and are already different between release and debug because of the difference in app signing.

Answer (score 1):

From android [build variants docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html),

> Gradle automatically creates build variants based on your build types and product flavors, and names them according to `product-flavor Build-Type`

So in your case you have 4 variants already. And if you want different source sets for them you can have them as follows
`src/flavor1Debug`
`src/flavor2Release` and so on.. Notice the naming convention

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
productFlavors {
            flavor1 {
                    applicationId   "com.myapp.flavor1"
                    }
            flavor2 {
                    applicationId   "com.myapp.flavor2"
                    }
            }

            sourceSets.flavor1 {
                res {
                    srcDir 'flavor1'
                }
                resources {
                    srcDir 'flavor1'
                }
            }

            sourceSets.flavor2 {
                res {
                    srcDir 'flavor2'
                }
                resources {
                    srcDir 'flavor2'
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: The different resources works for release (i.e src/flavor1, src/flavor2) but not for debug. I don't see why your solution would fix that?